# Two NIC on same server same network with static routing

Tags: networking

I have setup ubuntu server 16.04.
Have put two network cards, both to connect to a single network of 172.18.6.0/24
They have different IPs in that if one goes down, the other can keep up activity.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 172.18.6.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.18.6.1
# eth1 config
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 172.18.6.102
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.18.6.1
```

but aftersetup, I realise one NIC is connecting and the other is not connecting.
both show up when i do

```
ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:00:5a:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.6.101/24 brd 172.18.6.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe00:5a12/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:00:5a:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.6.102/24 brd 172.18.6.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe00:5a13/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can i have both NICs active?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What do you mean one is not connecting? Do you mean the link won't go up? Care to share a bit more info about your setup? Also, can you edit your question and post the output of `ip link show`?

Comment: With "packet routing" - see `man ip-route`

Comment: I dont know what changed, but later on. Both NIC started working. I can access the server through any of the IPs.

Thanks.